# Can't inflate fragment with "custom_list_users.xml" in UserRecyclerAdapter class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

So I'm trying to display the recyclerview and its contents in a fragment. My recyclerview is displaying fine, but the User object I want to display inside the recyclerview is not.

I got the user's name from the database and want to set it to a textview to display. The name is being retrieved from Firebase perfectly, so it should be displaying on the recyclerview. I have inflated the "custom_lists_users.xml"(my custom view to display every user) into the UserRecyclerAdap (my adapter) class.

However, I'm assuming it didn't inflate properly, because if it did then I would see my User's name in the fragment's recyclerview where I inflated.

I have attached two classes where I think the problems are, Pls do let me know if I'm missing something. Thanks!

**UserRecyclerAdap class:**

```
public class UserRecyclerAdap extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserRecyclerAdap.ViewHolder> {
private Context context;
private List<User> users;

public UserRecyclerAdap(Context context, List<User> users) {
    this.context = context;
    this.users = users;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.custom_list_users, parent, false);
    Log.d("layoutInflater", "inflated!");
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int i) {
    String userName = users.get(i).getName();
    holder.name.setText(userName);
    Log.d("bindViewHolder", holder.name.toString());
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return users.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView name;
    ImageView profilePic;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.name);

    }
}
```

}

**UserFragment class**

```
public class UsersFragment extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private List<User> users;
private UserRecyclerAdap userRecyclerAdap;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_users, container, false);
    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));

    users = new ArrayList<>();

    readUsers();

    return view;
}

public void readUsers() {
    final FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("USERS");

    //goes thru everythig stored in firebase database
    reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            users.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                //goes thru every object in db and makes a user obj out of data
                User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);

                assert user != null;
                assert firebaseUser != null;
                if(user.getID().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())) {
                    users.add(user);
                }
            }
            userRecyclerAdap = new UserRecyclerAdap(getContext(), users);
            recyclerView.setAdapter(userRecyclerAdap);
        }


        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

}

**custom_list_users.xml file**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/profilePic"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="-1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user2_foreground"
            tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user2_foreground" />


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="192dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Name"
            android:textSize="36sp" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you please share your  **custom_lists_users.xml** file

Comment: I have updated my post with the file. Hope it helps. Thank u so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please replace your **custom_list_users.xml file** with below

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profilePic"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user2_foreground"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_user2_foreground" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textSize="36sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No Sir, that did not work unfortunately. However, I am getting a message in my console like this "E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout". Do you think my problem lies here by any chance? I Log.d every detail and its showing my user's credentials being stored and retrieved from Firebase perfectly. However, something is going on when it is trying to attach adapter to recyclerView

Comment: Actually Sir, I have found the problem. Thank u so much for your time!